# How to handle these inverted duplexed serial protocol in Arduino?

Tags: arduino, serial

I have a device that communicates with an inverted duplexed serial protocol like the following:

[image]

I need to communicate with this device with Arduino.
I tried to send

- simply UART serial text to channel 1
- its inverted signal to channel 0
  But failed because, on channel 1, I need to send a tiny signal at start and end.

How can I achieve these protocols with Arduino?
Or is there a standardized named protocol?

Comment: What device it is? That looks like it uses RS-485 (or RS-422) interface for differential signaling, so you must too.

Comment: The device is brushless motor. 'differential signaling'. Is it possible to send the signal programmatically? Or require some hardware?

Comment: Sorry again, 'RS-485 (or RS-422) interface for differential signaling'. That is the answer. I'll try with these protocols. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like the serial data is transmitted over a differential bus, such as RS-485 or RS-422. You need a receiver or tranceiver for it to receive it as standard CMOS or TTL logic levels.